# How to capture milliseconds value with millis() using Processing?

Tags: java, processing

I'm currently working with Processing. I would like to execute a function 4 seconds after its call. I tried using `millis()` by taking a value at a certain time and comparing. But when I write:

```
final int m = millis();
```

The value of `m` changes at the same time `millis()` changes.

How can I capture a constant value of `millis()`?

PS. I've tried using `final` and `static`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to scope the variable at the sketch level, outside of the `draw()` function so that you aren't recreating it every time. You also need to compare the variable to the current time. Something like this:

```
int startTime;

void setup(){
  startTime = millis();
}

void draw(){
  int currentTime = millis();
  if(currentTime > startTime + 5000){
    background(255, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

I'd also recommend doing a search on Stack Overflow for the `millis()` function.